# Get a specific value from a table with using a few conditions in Python

Tags: arcpy, table, conditional

I have a table that each different values in the table is the result of a combination of different conditions. For example in the below image the condition is as follow: if coverType=fallow , Treatment=Crop Residue Cover, Condition/ImperviousArea=Good, SoilType=C then the value is equal to 83.

I want to have a tool which asks the user to choose a value from each column (e.g. choose CoverType; SoilType, ...) and then return the related number as output. Do you have any thoughts how should I do this?

So far I have just the first lines of the code as below:

[image]

```
import arcpy
path= r'H\Python\FinalProject\RunOff.gdb'
arcpy.env.workspace= path
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

table=r'H\Python\FinalProject\RunOff.gdb\CN.csv'
cursor= arcpy.SearchCursor(table)
#CN= ?? # I don't know this part!
#S=(1000/CN) - 10
#I = 0.2(S)
#P = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
#out_feature_class = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but I think that you should be thinking about your *where clause* of your cursor then reading the row(s) returned (row = cursor.next() then row.getValue('Field')). I would suggest that an arcpy.da.SearchCursor might be the better way to go but if you're happy with arcpy.SearchCursor don't forget to del your cursor when you're done with it.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a script tool that has the four fields with drop-downs of the possible values that allows the user to pick possible values, this script should work to return the desired value.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\GIS\SE\GISSE.gdb"
tbl = "LookupTable"

coverType = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
treatment = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
condition = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
soilType = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

st = "ST_{0}".format(soilType)

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tbl, ["CoverType", "Treatment", "Condition", st]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0].upper() == coverType.upper() and row[1].upper() == treatment.upper() and row[2].upper() == condition.upper():
            arcpy.AddMessage("Soil type value = {0}".format(row[3]))
```

It checks for the values of `CoverType`, `Treatment`, `Condition`, and then returns the value of the soil type field based on the letter entered.

So coverType = "fallow", treatment = "Crop Residue Cover", condition = "Good", soilType = "B" will return `Soil type value = 83` (as highlighted in your table above).

Here is how I set up my gdb table - I did prefix the soiltype fields as I don't like field names with a single character, but that's personal preference.

[image]